# Info path rules for two related fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

I have info path form that has signature and status field and I want to make a condition when signatures field not blank the status field will show a message.

Basically, when signer 1 done then I need status to show Ready for signer 2
And when signer 2 done I need the status to show Ready for signer 3.

Is it possible on info path designer I have difficulty to applied the action is that b/c the control is signature?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You should create rules to achieve this. I don't know your column types but basically rules at all column types are similar and I did this for text column. You can to this for signature 2 field too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @newie The problem I have is signature is not input group it is object and it will consider it as a field

Comment: What do you mean it is an object? Are you saying it's an image file or something similar?