# InfoPath rules for two related fields(Edited)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that has signature and status fields and I want to make a condition that when the signatures field is not blank, the status field will show a message.

Basically, when signer 1 done then I need status to show Ready for signer 2. And when signer 2 is done I need the status to show Ready for signer 3.

Is it possible in InfoPath designer I have difficulty to applied the action is that b/c the control is signature?

Note:
My Signature is Digital signature (Not input category)

Comment: Both are my question I made correction or edited !!!

Comment: Same question. One needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though this sounds like a job for both InfoPath (conditionally hiding fields) and a workflow (moving from one signer to another).

From MS Office support [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-a-control-based-on-values-on-the-form-0cfd584f-8e52-479d-9419-df2c4231d72e):

1. On the form template, click the control that you want to hide.
2. On the Format menu, click Conditional Formatting.
3. In the Conditional Formatting dialog box, click Add.
4. Under If this condition is true, set the condition that you want.
   For example, to hide the control that you selected in step 1 only
   when a certain value is entered into another control on the form
   template, select that second control in the first box, and then
   specify the value that will determine whether to hide the control
   that you selected in step 1.
5. Under Then apply this formatting, click Hide this control.
6. To save the condition and return to the form template, click OK
   twice.
7. To test your changes, click Preview on the Standard toolbar, or
   press CTRL+SHIFT+B.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more please ? and the workflow too? Tnx

Comment: Can you clarify what you'd like more clarity on?

Comment: Look at this answer , my problem is the signature is Digital. How can I do ?   https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222384/info-path-rules-for-two-related-fields/222395#222395

Comment: That is why I made "correction" on my question